# xorg crashing on compiz --replace

Tags: gnome, xorg, compiz, crash

I use Ubuntu 19.10 on my Dell Lattitude E5520, and whenever I run compiz --replace, ubuntu tells me that a problem has occurred and to log out, even if nothing is enabled. I also tried GNOME compatibility. Here is my log: [Xserver log - Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/v6WnDhQy). I have all default settings, and only the default apps, chrome, blender, Spotify, Minecraft, and Vim. PLZ HELP!!!

Comment: you cannot use gnome with compiz. you must try different DE like MATE. sorry!